# Lower the minimum brightness without third party apps

Tags: root-access, xiaomi, screen-brightness

My default lowest brightness value is around `33`. I can't go lower than that from the brightness slider. `33` is too bright for me. I want to take it even lower near `15`. Although I can lower it to `15` by modifying the `brightness` file located in `sys/class/backlight/` it is temporary. So I want an permanent solution like changing some values here and there. I don't want to use an third party app as they're inconvenient and create issues oftentimes.

I'm using Pocophone with a custom ROM Android 11. And I have Root access with Magisk 24. So I can do pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0):

A Magisk module [BrightHack OP7T](https://github.com/Geofferey/op7t-brighthack) would help you.

> A simple Magisk module for lowering the minimum brightness

I'm assuming you know the basics.

Comment: Is it only for OnePlus device? Or the other devices are supported as well?

Comment: Should work on other devices as well, judging from the code.